# Proper way to enable SSE4 on a per-function / per-block of code basis?

Tags: xcode, clang, llvm, sse

For one of my OS X programs, I have a few optimized cases which use SSE4.1 instructions.  On SSE3-only machines, the non-optimized branch is ran:

```
// SupportsSSE4_1 returns true on CPUs that support SSE4.1, false otherwise
if (SupportsSSE4_1()) {

    // Code that uses _mm_dp_ps, an SSE4 instruction

    ...

    __m128 hDelta   = _mm_sub_ps(here128, right128);
    __m128 vDelta   = _mm_sub_ps(here128, down128);

    hDelta = _mm_sqrt_ss(_mm_dp_ps(hDelta, hDelta, 0x71));
    vDelta = _mm_sqrt_ss(_mm_dp_ps(vDelta, vDelta, 0x71));

    ...

} else {
    // Equivalent code that uses SSE3 instructions
    ...
}
```

In order to get the above to compile, I had to set `CLANG_X86_VECTOR_INSTRUCTIONS` to `sse4.1`.

However, this seems to instruct clang that it's ok to use the `ROUNDSD` instruction anywhere in my program.  Hence, the program is crashing on SSE3-only machines with `SIGILL: ILL_ILLOPC`.

What's the best practice for enabling SSE4.1 for just the lines the code inside of true branch of the `SupportsSSE4_1()` if block?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is currently no way to target different ISA extensions at block / function granularity in clang.  You can only do it at *file* granularity (put your SSE4.1 code into a separate file and specify that file to use `-msse4.1`).  If this is an important feature for you, please file a bug report to request it!

However, I should note that the actually benefit of `DPPS` is pretty small in most real scenarios (and using `DPPS` even slows down some code sequences!).  Unless this particular code sequence is critical, and you have carefully measured the effect of using DPPS, it may not be worth the hassle to special case for SSE4.1 even if that compiler feature is available.

Comment: Thanks!  I ended up moving the function in question to it's own file and set up Xcode to compile that file twice (once with -msse4.1 and once with -msse3).  I then use preprocessor macros to generate two different versions of the functions and moved the SupportsSSE4_1() up a level to the calling function.  I'll re-profile the app, but last time I checked, the DPPS version was a bit faster.  Thanks for the heads up! :)

Comment: Yeah, I don't mean to suggest that one should never use DPPS.  Just that its benefit is *much* less than people often expect.

Comment: clang hopefully by now support [`__attribute__((target(sse4.1)))` on functions, the way gcc does](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Function-Attributes.html).  So you can use different inline functions within the same compilation unit.

Comment: It does support this now. :)

Comment: Even the file level can get you in trouble with Clang for C++ code _if_ there are global constructors, like a static string. Also see [Restrict global constructors to base ISA](https://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2018-December/128159.html) on the LLVM-dev mailing list. In the ml message, the function is AVX2 and source file was compiled with `-mavx2`. However, the constructors were not guarded like the function and crashed on a late 2011 MacBook Pro with Core2 Duo/SSE4.

Answer (score 6):

You can make a CPU dispatcher.  You can do this in one file but you have to compile twice.  First with SSE4.1 and then without and then link in the object file for SSE4.1.  The first time you call your fucntion `myfunc` it calls the function `myfunc_dispatch` which determines the instruction set and sets the pointer to either `myfunc_SSE41` or `myfunc_SSE3`.  The next time you call your func `myfunc` it jumps right to the function for your instruction set.

```
//clang -c -O3 -msse4.1 foo.cpp -o foo_sse41.o
//clang -O3 -msse3 foo.cpp foo_sse41.o   

typedef float MyFuncType(float*);

MyFuncType myfunc, myfunc_SSE41, myfunc_SSE3, myfunc_dispatch;
MyFuncType * myfunc_pointer = &myfunc_dispatch;

#ifdef __SSE4_1__
float myfunc_SSE41(float* a) {
    //SSE41 code
}
#else
float  myfunc_SSE3(float *a) {
    //SSE3 code
}

float myfunc_dispatch(float *a) {
    if(SupportsSSE4_1()) {
        myfunc_pointer = myfunc_SSE41;
    }
    else {
        myfunc_pointer = myfunc_SSE3;
    }
    myfunc_pointer(a);
}

float myfunc(float *a) {
    (*myfunc_pointer)(a);
}
int main() {
    //myfunc(a);
}
#endif
```

Comment: Not really though, I just got "error: instruction requires: AVX-512 ISA", and I have a dispatcher like you describe. Usually that works. clang can be a bit arrogant at times, if I said to shoot my foot in inline assembly or with intrinsics, I expect a hole in my foot.

Comment: @doug65536, check the assembly. I'm sure I could get it to work using the method I described.

Comment: If I add `-mavx512f` then it will use VEX encoding for all of the SSE in the file, breaking the ones for old SSE. gcc has a way of doing it on a per-function basis, but clang doesn't support `#pragma target`. I moved the avx ones to a separate file, and the avx512 ones to another file. That worked.

Comment: @doug65536, I don't see what the problem is. I have a KNL system with AVX512 I could test it on but I have other things to do. Why don't you ask a question on SO then I can answer it and test it on KNL. I can make a version for Clang, GCC, and ICC.  ICC will be more of a challenge because `-xMIC-AVX512` creates a dispatcher that I will need to override so that will make the question more interesting.

Comment: I don't need to ask a question because I already solved the problem. Just try using `vmovntdqa (%[src]),%%zmm0` in inline assembly in a source file that doesn't have `-mavx512f` and see for yourself if you don't believe that clang says "instruction requires: AVX-512 ISA". It accepts `vmovntdqa (%[src]),%%ymm0` just fine with no AVX architecture flags though. It's a (design?) bug in clang. Look [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c1e25a8e842089e8)

Comment: @doug65536, I still don't see the problem. So what if Clang complains that it wants `-mavx512f`. Put your AVX512 code inside a define block `#if defined ( __AVX512F__ ) || defined ( __AVX512__ )` and clang won't see it until you enable `-mavx512f`.

Comment: Which means it is multiple object files, like I said. You can't put it all in one compilation unit. I conceded that your technique mostly works, but I only pointed out that it doesn't always work. How do you dynamically dispatch to legacy version if the whole file is compiled with VEX encoding because of `-mavx512f`? You don't, you split it out and have separate object files.

Comment: @doug65536, of course you create separate object files for each instruction set you target. I thought that was clear in my answer? Look at the top of the code. See `foo.cpp foo_sse41.o`?  If you wanted to target say SSE2, SSE4.1, AVX2, and AVX512 you would have use `foo.cpp foo_sse41.o, foo_avx2.o, foo_avx512.o`. Each of those has to be compiled from a separate translation unit. But they can all come from the same file.

Comment: The file `foo.cpp` is compiled with the lowest common denominator which for 64-bit code is SSE2. The answer to "How do you dynamically dispatch to legacy version if the whole file is compiled with VEX encoding because of -mavx512f" is that the dispatcher should only be running from the lowest common denominator instruction set.

Comment: @Zboson, Is there a portable (Windows, macOS, Linux) C Code (Header) for detection CPU Features? Something like `hasAVX()`, `hasSSE3()`, etc.. Thank You.

Comment: @Royi, yes, see the file `instrset_detect.cpp` in Agner Fog's VCL http://www.agner.org/optimize/vectorclass.zip

Answer (score 5):

Depending on the OS you might be able to use something like Function Multiversioning in the future. I'm working on the feature right now, but it'll be a while before it's ready for use in a production compiler.

See http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FunctionMultiVersioning for more details.

Comment: OP is using Clang, not GCC. Clang lacks the feature, not GCC. Worse, Clang will pretend it is GCC by defining `__GNUC__` and then get into a code path it cannot handle. It gets old working around the same Clang crap time and time again...

Comment: Well, it's been implemented from the time I wrote that comment to well before you wrote your comment so I'm not sure what you're talking about here in this one, or you're just looking to complain.